# Tell me about what lights you use!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

I'm going to be doing some blog posts reviewing bicycle taillights. Based on recommendations I've read in posts on this site, and the highly-rated and best-selling lights at various online retailers, I've compiled a list of lights that I think would be good to test. But first, I'd like to know what lights are most-used by the Bicycles.SE community, so that if I'm missing any popular ones, I can add them to the review.

**Please take [this quick online survey](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dENoaC14R3JNaWo3ZXpDZVZ2RmZvOUE6MQ)** about what lights you use. Note that I'm primarily looking at lights in the $15-40 range, so if you have some super-fancy 50 watt $300 light, we're probably not going to review it. Nevertheless, include it in the survey — we'd like to know what's out there.

I'm still working out the details with Sam, our local CHAOS member, but we're also planning to run a promotion contest in January to give away some safety lights once the review is over.

Comment: I basically use a superflash and a Dinotte rechargeable helmet light. I also have spoke lights on all my bikes, but didn't have any space to put that. (Those would also make for good giveaways.)